# Javascript InsertBefore - in a different div both within a parent div

Tags: javascript

I would like to insert an hr element in a different child div (2 child divs within a parent div), as per the set-up below. The insertbefore method works fine for an element within the same div but not for elements in the other child div (see code below). Is there a different method I can use to achieve this or do I want the impossible?

```
<body>

<div id="whole section">

<div id="group_a">
<h3 id="event_1">Heading 1</h3>    
<p> some text </p>

**// I would like to insert an hr element here**

<h3 id="event_2">Heading 2</h3>
<p> more text </p>

</div>

<div id="group_b">

**// I can only insert code here though**

<script type="text/javascript">
function add_hr(){
  var new_hr = document.createElement('hr');
  var reference = document.getElementById('event_2');
  document.body.insertBefore(new_hr, reference);
}

window.onload = function(){add_hr();};

</script>

</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) requires that the reference element be a direct child of the element on which you call it. Your line

```
document.body.insertBefore(new_hr, reference);
```

...tells the browser to insert `new_hr` before the `reference` element directly contained by `document.body`. But `document.body` **doesn't** directly contain the reference element, it's inside a `div`. So you get an error, because the reference element can't be found *directly* inside the element you're inserting into.

You can fix that by using the reference element's parent:

```
reference.parentNode.insertBefore(new_hr, reference);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ipudiy/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ipudiy/1/edit)

Comment: You are of course correct. Unfortunately it turns out the actual reason I couldn't figure out how to make this work is because the parentNode in question has contentEditable set to false. Thanks anyway and sorry I can't up-vote you, I still lack the points.

Comment: @Ronelz: My example's parent node also has `contentEditable` set to `false` (because `false` is the default). Are you sure that's what's wrong?

Comment: Reasonably sure. To be precise - contentEditable = inherit and iscontenteditable=false. I copied the relevant piece of code into the TryIt Editor at W3schools and it worked just fine but still nothing happens on the actual page. I've been playing with some js to see whether I can change contentEditable to true but no luck so far - it appears to be inheriting the property from a parent site that I can't access.